# Reusing fragment and get tab position in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I have a tabbedapplication. The layout in all the tabs are same. But the content will be different according to the json response. So I am trying to create single fragment and reuse in all the views. But I dont know how to get the tab position. So that I can call different webservices.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_all_employee, container, false);
    recyclerView_allemp = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_allemp);
    recyclerView_allemp.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
// need to get the tabposition 
    new EmployeeTask().execute("http://something.com");
    return view;
}
```

ViewPager oncreate :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_employee_screen);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ALL EMPLOYEES"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("MALE EMPLOYEES"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("FEMALE EMPLOYEES"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    final PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using ViewPager?

Comment: Yes. I am. Updated the code with viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Use below code you can get current position of your viewpager :

```
int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(position);
```

So here based on position you can decide what stuff have to do with that fragment.